# How to change package name after release?

Tags: ros, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've released a package named hpcl_rtt, for some reason i want to change the package name to micros_rtt.
I've done the local work in my repository. What else should i do in bloom?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217930/how-to-change-package-name-after-release?/) by [sukha](https://answers.ros.org/users/19709/sukha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-09-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bloom will scan your repository when run and should release the new package and not release the old package. The pull request will change the packages indexed to the current state of your repository and it should not need any more intervention.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-09-21**:
The already built packages with the old names should be removed from the apt repos then. I guess this has to be done manually.

**Comment by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) on 2017-04-10**:
how about changing repository on Github web-site in other computer without bloom? should we any thing when we like to change package name? @tfoote